# Delphi: load BASS DLL and play MP3

Tags: delphi, function, mp3, bass.dll

I want to load a [bass dll](http://www.un4seen.com/) manually from somewhere and then play a mp3 file. How to do that? Delphi XE2.

My attempt doesn't work:

```
type
  QWORD = Int64;
  HSTREAM = LongWord;
type
  TBASS_ChannelPlay = function(handle: HSTREAM; restart: LongBool): LongBool; stdcall;

type
  TBASS_StreamCreateFile = function(mem: LongBool; f: Pointer;
    offset, length: QWORD; flags: LongWord): HSTREAM; stdcall;

procedure PlayMP3(FileName: string);
var
  BASS_ChannelPlay: TBASS_ChannelPlay;
  BASS_StreamCreateFile: TBASS_StreamCreateFile;
  DllHandle: THandle;
  MP3Stream: HSTREAM;
  DllPath:string;
  pFileName:pchar;
begin
  DllPath:= 'c:\dll\bass.dll';
  DllHandle := LoadLibrary(pchar(DLLPath));
  try
    if DllHandle = 0 then
      Exit;
    @BASS_StreamCreateFile := GetProcAddress(DllHandle,
      'BASS_StreamCreateFile');
    if @BASS_StreamCreateFile <> nil then
    begin
      pfilename:=pchar(FileName);
      MP3Stream := BASS_StreamCreateFile(false, Pfilename, 0, 0, 0);
      if MP3Stream <> 0 then
      begin
        @BASS_ChannelPlay := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'BASS_ChannelPlay');
        if @BASS_ChannelPlay <> nil then
          BASS_ChannelPlay(MP3Stream,false);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(DllHandle);
  end;
end;
```

**But BASS_StreamCreateFile returns 0 all time :(**

The code from their example (Bass Test) and Bass.pas:

```
type
  DWORD = LongWord;
  BOOL = LongBool;
  QWORD = Int64;
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: Pointer; offset, length: QWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM; {$IFDEF WIN32}stdcall{$ELSE}cdecl{$ENDIF}; external bassdll;

strs: array[0..128] of HSTREAM;

procedure TForm1.Button15Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    f: PChar;
begin
    if not OpenDialog2.Execute then Exit;
    f := PChar(OpenDialog2.FileName);
    strs[strc] := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, f, 0, 0, 0 {$IFDEF UNICODE} or BASS_UNICODE {$ENDIF});
    if strs[strc] <> 0 then
    begin
        ListBox3.Items.Add(OpenDialog2.FileName);
        Inc(strc);
    end
    else
        Error('Error creating stream!');
end;
```

### Added

```
  MP3Stream := BASS_StreamCreateFile(false, Pfilename, 0, 0, 0);
  ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
```

`GetLastError` doesn't show any errors!

### Added

There is BASS 2.4 Delphi unit (dynamic) too.

It's written:

> How to install    Copy DYNAMIC_BASS.PAS to the \LIB subdirectory of
>   your Delphi path or your project dir   Call Load_BASSDLL (eg. in
>   FormCreate) to load BASS before using any functions, and
>   Unload_BASSDLL (eg. in FormDestory) to unload it when you're done.
>
> NOTE: Delphi 2009 users should use the BASS_UNICODE flag where
>   possible

I do:

```
 if Load_BASSDLL(DllPath) then
  begin
  FileName:='C:\Users\V\Desktop\cmd.mp3';
  MP3Stream:=BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, pchar(FileName), 0, 0, 0 {$IFDEF UNICODE} or BASS_UNICODE {$ENDIF});
    if MP3Stream <> 0 then
     BASS_ChannelPlay(MP3Stream, False);
     Unload_BASSDLL;
  end;
```

It still doesn't work :(

### Added:

If to do

```
BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, Form1.Handle, nil);
```

then `BASS_ChannelPlay(MP3Stream, False)` returns true but I don't hear a sound:(

Comment: Again, read my edited answer. If you look at `dynamic_bass.pas`, especially the code for `Load_BASSDLL`, it does NOT call `BASS_Init`. It simply loads the library and does all of the `GetProcAddress` calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the call to `BASS_Init`. From the same demo you quoted from, in the `FormCreate` event:

```
// Initialize audio - default device, 44100hz, stereo, 16 bits
if not BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, Handle, nil) then
  Error('Error initializing audio!');
```

Also, look at the demo source's call:

```
BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, f, 0, 0, 
 0 {$IFDEF UNICODE} or BASS_UNICODE {$ENDIF});
```

Note what happens with the last parameter? The `or BASS_UNICODE` is required on D2009 and up, unless you're using `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar`; Delphi's default string type is `UnicodeString`, and the default `PChar` is `PWideChar`.

You can use it with the `{$IFDEF UNICODE}` or without it; Delphi defines `UNICODE`, so if you use it your code will be backwards-compatible with earlier versions of Delphi (pre-D2009) as well.

You should also look at `dynamic_bass.pas` in the `Bass\Delphi\dynamic` folder. It has code to dynamically load the library and retrieve all the functions; if you don't want to use it directly, at least you could copy the function definitions and dynamic loading code you need from there instead.

Comment: I added `or $80000000 (BASS_UNICODE const)`, `BASS_StreamCreateFile` returns "0"

Comment: Where are you trying to create the file (what filename)? What Windows version are you using? Is this a 32 or 64 bit project?

Comment: A file path is "c:\users\v\desktop\1.mp3"; Windows 7 x32; 32 bit project.

Comment: I don't know what else it might be, then. I really don't understand why you're making it so complicated for yourself, though; you have a perfectly good demo that you could just copy and paste code from and then remove the references the the `OpenDialog` and `ListBox` from and change to accepting the filename as a parameter. You also insist on doing things like hard-coding constants that are already defined (`BASS_UNICODE`, but you hard-coded `$80000000` instead of just using it), and manually loading the DLL and using `GetProcAddress` instead of just statically loading it.

Comment: The DLL mustn't be in application's folder because it's a single-file application (only EXE). I don't want to keep the program on a desktop with the DLL (but somewhere in a temporary folder). It's not a big project with many many files, including DLLs, where keeping them with EXE is normal.

Comment: And the most main - I will use the DLL very rarely! I don't need Static Loading (it's not a player).

Comment: Fair enough. See my edited answer. (I just downloaded Bass 2.4 from the link you gave, unzipped it into a folder, opened `BTMain.pas` in Notepad++, and glanced at the code.)

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! BASS_ChannelPlay(MP3Stream, False) return true...but I don't hear a sound :(

Comment: You could accept my answer, then. :) Not hearing a sound is a separate question; this one (with all your edits and the comment discussion) has become pretty noisy.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion - just don't load the .dll manually.  Forget "LoadDll" and ESPECIALLY forget all that grungy, low-level Win3.0 era "GetProcAddress()" nonsense.

Just declare an external, just like the working Bass sample code successfully does:

```
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(
           mem: BOOL; 
           f: Pointer; 
           offset, length: QWORD; 
           flags: DWORD): HSTREAM; 
{$IFDEF WIN32}stdcall{$ELSE}cdecl{$ENDIF}; external bassdll;
```

PS:
If you really, really, REALLY insist on LoadDll () and friends, then:

1. Remember that Delphi XE strings are now 16-bit Unicode
2. Check GetLastError () to determine exactly *WHY* LoadDll returned a null handle.

PPS:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to use bass.dll
http://delphimagic.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/escuchar-la-radio-por-streaming.html

Comment: Since your website is in spanish and this is an english-based site, consider explaining how to get the source code (if someone doesn't understand spanish is going to be a bit difficult).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It is often a good idea to post a concise code fragment instead of linking to external resources for several reasons: (1) the external resource may disappear in the future, rendering your answer void (2) typically, links contain too much irrelevant information which may confuse people.